# JQuery dialog box from asp.net web project

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, ascx

So I am trying to implement a dialog box pop up when the user clicks on a menu button on my page for example About-Button which will display information regarding the web page. So, I have implemented a jquery function and a ascx page for the above.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#aboutButton').click(function(event) {
         alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );//testing
         $(function () {
         $("#aboutButtonDiv").load('aboutButton.ascx');
         $("#aboutButtonDiv").dialog({
             backdrop: 'static',
             draggable: false,
             position: {
                my: "center top",
                at: "center top+100",
                of: window
             },
             dialogClass: "no-close",               
             resizable: false,
             height: 'auto',
             width: 500,
             modal: true,
             buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                }
             }
          })
      })
  })
  $(".menu-close").hide();
});
```

My ascx code is a simple div tag

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="aboutButton.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebProj.aboutButton" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="aboutButtonDiv" title="About">
        <p>Hello this is my first dialog using JQuery</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I am clicking the button the click event is firing(I can see the Thanks for visiting message) but the dialog which I want doesn't pop-up. Am I missing something in Jquery code. In my main web page I have the following button

```
<li class="menutab-list">
    <a href="#" type="link" id="aboutButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAbout">
         <span class="listing-text">About</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine when I tested it. So it probably has something to do with missing jQuery UI files or parts of it.

In order for the Dialog to work you need the jQuery UI library. And even if you have that it could be that it is missing the specific Dialog part.

Go to http://jqueryui.com/download/ and create your download by selecting the options that you need or download the full package. You can check the includes on the third line of jquery-ui.js which parts are included.

And there is a jquery css file as well, with some icon images in the download that are also needed for the dialog to work properly.

Comment: I have the following script tags <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> Still its not working

Comment: Did you add `jquery-ui.css` also?

Comment: and you need to add `http://` to the script tag if you want to get it from another website.

Comment: Yes i have the above mentioned code. I am using this online reference doc https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/622905/Implementation-of-Dialog-Box-using-jQuery-UI-Libra .

Comment: Sorry, even when I copy and paste the code from that link I get a working dialog. Are you sure there are no javascript errors or whatnot?

Comment: good catch. When I ran in IE I got this error message when clicked 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139794/discussion-between-user3324848-and-vdwwd).

Comment: They the libraries are still missing. Download the package and use the files locally and see if that works better.